# Threading and screen kind of stops and closed forms are still displaying

Tags: c#

I have multiple forms that pop up during an intensive operation. For example, when a form pops up asking the user for something, and the user clicks OK, the form's graphics stay on the main screen, even though it is closed.

How can I make it so that these graphics disappear completely? I'm using `System.Threading.Thread.sleep(10)` to pause the application for a bit, but the screen kind of stops and the changes are not clear. What should I do?

Comment: WinForms? Silverlight? WPF? Code that demonstrates the problem? Please read the FAQ before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Example code? We need something to look at to see what you are working on.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: BTW, Thread.Sleep will stop all processing (including your form) when executed on the main thread (a.k.a. the GUI thread). The GUI thread must pump windows messages which it can't do while the thread is paused.

Comment: you need to look into background workers and delegation. it sounds like your UI thread is being blocked. You need to do your intensive operation in an asynchronous thread to the UI.

Comment: popups are running on main thread and due to which each time, when a popup display, main thread goes to sleep for 10 ms. When several popups suddenly display, then main thread goes to sleep for longer period. It would be nice if you show some code. You can use Tasks to display each pop up and task will run on different threads....

Comment: I don't see why this question should be closed. It is pretty clear what's being asked...?

Answer (score 3):

The closed form's "graphics" remain visible as long as the form was closed over an underlying window that now is not able to process any window messages (especially for redrawing itself).

To avoid this, you either have to call `Application.DoEvents()` (which only works in WinForms and is usually not recommended) after closing the child form, or you need to put the code that causes the message pump to be blocked into a separate thread, for example using a `BackgroundWorker` or a `Task`, which is highly recommended if you want to keep your application responsive.

The same goes for `Thread.Sleep(10)`. This blocks the current (UI-)thread from processing any messages, so the window isn't responsive for that period of time.